# Remove UILabels from UITableViewCell and add them again

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm removing labels from a `UITableViewCell` because i don't need them in that particular cell. The problem is when the cell is reused i need them but they were removed before.

```
if (post.blockContent == TRUE) {
        [cell.titleLabel removeFromSuperview];
        [cell.contentLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

How do i add them again to the `UITableViewCell`?

I remove them because i have constraints linking everything with a dynamic cell height and i can't simply hide them because that will just make a empty space in the middle of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
  // set visibile for all cell
 [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.titleLabel];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.contentLabel];
 // when contindition statisfy it will be hide
if (post.blockContent == TRUE) {
    [cell.titleLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.contentLabel removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

**choice-2**

```
 cell.titleLabel.hidden = NO;
 cell.contentLabel.hidden = NO;

  if (post.blockContent == TRUE) {
    cell.titleLabel.hidden = YES;
   cell.contentLabel.hidden = YES;
  }
```

Comment: That will add them to the coordinates (0,0)

Comment: The 2nd choice is not relevant like i explained in the question beforehand. The 1st choice adds the labels to the CGPointZero, and once we remove them, the constraints are also remove.

Comment: @bruno - if first choice works add the constraints also , on addsubview surely works

Comment: theres no point in having a xib with components if i'm adding them by code.

Answer (score 0):

the tableview reused the cell.
because this reason you cant used removeFromSuperview because all the cells that used the same instance will remove the labels.

the solution is the used constraint.
you need to wrap the labels to view, and the other objects will have constraint that skip over the view and reduce the constant of the cell.

in the heightForRow you need to calc the height without the view .

changed priority at runtime , its the main idea for the solution.